# Taylor Series with respect to only a subset of inputs

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ whose input I can partition into two sets of variables $f(x) = f(y, z)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^p$ and $z\in\mathbb{R}^{n-p}$.

Can I do a Taylor expansion with respect to only $z$? Rather than doing
$$
f(x + h) = f(x) + h\nabla_x f(x) + \frac{h^2}{2} \nabla_{x}^2f(x) + \mathcal{O}(||h||^3)
$$
Can I do
$$
f(y, z + k) = f(y, z) + k\nabla_zf(y, z) + \frac{k^2}{2}\nabla_z^2 f(y, z)  + \mathcal{O}(||h||^3)
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, and with that formula you have written (except the mixed up $h$'s and $k$'s and you should probably somehow include into your notation that the Hessian $\nabla^2$ is a bilinear form getting twice the argument $k$).

What should prevent you from doing so? You simply consider the function
$$
\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R}^{n-p}\to\mathbb{R}^m,~\tilde{f}(z)=f(y,z)
$$
which inherits all differentiability properties from $f$.

Edit:
you need to include all "bilinear approximations" (bi- for the second derivative) of your function. This is actually abroad of your question and rather general for multivariate Taylor polynomials. In
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor%27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions)
you can look up the general formula.

For example, the second order Taylor polynomial for $(x,y)\mapsto\exp(x+y)$ in $(0,0)$ does not only include the terms
$$
1+x+y+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}
$$
(which is how I would understand your notation), but also the off-diagonal/mixed-2nd-order-partial-derivatives term $xy$.

Comment: Thank you! So if my formula wrong (apart from $\mathcal{O}(||h||^3)$)